# How can I discover and read active Android notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

How can I discover and read active Android notifications? If there is any way to launch them directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the standard Android notifications from the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html), then No, there is no way to discover and read active notifications.  If you have access to the Android source code, you could modify the NotificationManagerService to provide this type of behavior.

If you're only concerned about duplicating notifications, the NotifcationManager has a built in system for preventing duplicate notifications.

As far as "launching them directly", I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do.  What is it that you're trying to do that you can't accomplish using the functionality outlined here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to find out. did you mean the notification with other apps? or cloud to device message?(C2DM). If you want catch the messages from google(C2DM) you can catch the messages with broadcastreciever in your application service. check the c2dm or notification service in google docs